# I need a list of AdMob Functions SWIFT

Tags: swift, admob, banner, interstitial

I've looked all over google's AdMob site, I just want a list of all the inbuilt functions I can use for banners and interstitials.
eg. `adViewDidReceiveAd() interstitialDidDismissScreen()`

If anyone knows where I can find this, please let me know.

Comment: please check the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bannerView functions where you have to implement `GADBannerViewDelegate` to be able to use it (don't forget to set the delegate for your banner as `myBanner.delegate = self` so they will be called).

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {

}
func adViewDidDismissScreen(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {

}
func adViewWillDismissScreen(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {

}
func adViewWillPresentScreen(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {

}
func adViewWillLeaveApplication(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {

}
func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {

}
```

And for interstitial delegates you will need to implement `GADInterstitialDelegate` to able to use it.(don't forget to set the delegate for your interstitlal as `interstitial.delegate = self` so they will be called).

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

}
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

}
func interstitialWillDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

}
func interstitialWillPresentScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

}
func interstitialWillLeaveApplication(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

}
func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {

}
```

Implement these after class declaration, ex: `class test:GADInterstitialDelegate {}`

Comment: Thanks so much for this!